# Use External PDFMerger Library in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, class, controller, pdf-generation, laravel-5

I have a `PDFMerger` library that I put in `App/Libraries/PDFmerger/`.
Inside that folder, there is some other classes and folders:

`PDFmerger`:

- **fpdf (folder)**

  - fpdf.php
- **fpdi (folder)**

  - **filters (folder)**
  - fpdf_tpl.php
  - fpdi.php
  - fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php
  - fpdi_pdf_parser.php
  - pdf_context.php
  - pdf_parser.php
- PDFMerger.php

How do I use all the classes inside these folders? What should I modify in all those classes so the controller can call them?

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less covered [here](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/).

Each external class needs a `namespace` declared:

```
namespace App\Libraries\PDFmerger\fpdf\fpdf;  //For example
```

Then your controller needs to `use` that:

```
use App\Libraries\PDFmerger\fpdf\fpdf;
```